# Web Audio API decode issue in safari

Tags: safari, web-audio-api

Web Audio API decodeAudioData of audiocontext is not decoding the m4a file of ios, except m4a file it decodes all the files in safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

Very vague. It may be you are using an unsurported media format. The M4A is just the container and does not specify the audio type inside. If you are trying to decode ALAC or a DRM AAC file, it will not work.

From https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW9

> Safari on iOS (including iPad) currently supports uncompressed WAV and AIF audio, MP3 audio, and AAC-LC or HE-AAC audio. HE-AAC is the preferred format.